# Change Date format to string date format not working?

Tags: javascript, c#

i have date in this format:

```
06/10/41 12:00:00 ص
```

I want to change it to string format like this:

```
441/10/06
```

My query is,

```
var date = '@Model.DecisionDate';
var newDate = date.toString('yyyy/MM/dd');
alert(newDate);
```

When I `alert` the value it returns the same date: `06/10/41 12:00:00 ص`. It does not change its format. Why is this happening?

Comment: Format the C# `DecisionDate` using `ToStirng` before assigning to javascript's `date` variable. Javascript `toString` doesn't have overrides with desired formats.

Comment: `var date='..'` is a string, so `string.toString` won't reformat anything - you need to convert it to a date first  eg `var newDate = new Date(date)` - but it needs to be in the correct format for js to parse it.  As above, much easier to output the date you already have in the correct format `date = '@Model.Decision.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd)' (or so)

Comment: @freesomn can you please let me know how to change it to my desire formate after changing it in date format in jquery